# using WebView class in windows store app development

Tags: windows-8

I have written the following code in c# for a button click to view a web page:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ob = new WebView();
        Uri search=new Uri("http://www.google.com");

        ob.Navigate(search);
    }
```

but whenever i click the button the above action is not being performed , what's wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

What i can see here is you are creating a new webview so either "**specify height and width to webview**" or "**add webview control to xaml with some name and specific height and width**."